# Превратить SQL запрос в LINQ выражение

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Есть запрос вида:

```
select count(id) as Count, ClassroomId, LessonNumber from Applications
where LessonNumber = 4
group by ClassroomId, LessonNumber
```

Я хочу в коде присвоить переменной результат count().

Comment: ну так и в чем проблема? Что то сами пытались? Что не получилось?

Comment: `var applicationsCount = applications
.Where(a => a.Classrooms.Number == classrooomNumber)
.Select(a => new { applications.Count, a.ClassroomId, app.LessonNumber })
.GroupBy(a => new { a.ClassroomId, a.LessonNumber })
.Count();` всегда возвращает 1

Comment: вы же не первый день на сайте - все ваши попытки добавляйте в вопрос

Comment: ну и вы не можете `присвоить переменной результат count()`, так как результат `Linq` запроса - коллекция, и у каждого элемнта внуктри коллекции будет свой `Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой получился linq

```
var app = from a in applications
          where a.Classrooms.Number == classrooomNumber
          group a by new { a.ClassroomId, a.LessonNumber }
          into a
          select new { Count = a.Count()};
```

И далее в коде можно будет использовать

```
app.FirstOrDefault().Count
```

Comment: `select new { Count = a.Count(), ClassroomId = a.ClassroomId, LessonNumber = a.LessonNumber }`